# How to customize Meteor accounts-ui modal popup dialogs?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I wanna add custom styling to meteor `accounts-ui` password reset model pop up dialog. Without adding `accounts-ui-unstyled` how can I do this? Is there a way to open our custom template for password reset link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add in the code for the accounts-ui-unstyled package in *somehow* so there isn't a way to avoid that.

You could do this if you want: Create a directory called `accounts-ui-unstyled` in your `/packages` folder and copy everything over from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled

You can add this package in with `meteor add accounts-ui-unstyled` and it should override the default package with the one you made manually and use your edits instead.

You can then edit it as you please.

Comment: Is this a proper way to do it ?

Comment: @BPSK Yes, why doesn't it seem so?